# View Test Case summary in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

I use Microsoft Test Manager for run Test Cases.
My preconditions for test is in Summary of Test Case.
When test case is run user can't see Summary.

Is there any approach to see Summary of Test Case on Test Run?

Comment: Could you please explain little bit more what is it about.
Are your Test Cases automated or do you run them manually?
Who are the "users"? Are they testers or do they just check results of the Test Runs?

Comment: Sorry for not clear description.
I have manual test cases. Its initial conditions are described in Summary(maybe there is more correct approach to describe it?).
When tester run test case he can't see this summary because during the run only steps are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not see the summary of the *Test Case* when you run it manually.
But there are another possibilities to display preconditions for the tester:

- **Using multi-line step(s)** 
  Store the preconditions in the "Action" part of a *Test Case* step and use this step as the first step in the test case.
  You can insert a line break using *Alt+Enter*
- **Using *Test Step* attachment**
  Store the preconditions in a document (called "Preconditions" so the testers know what it is)
  Attach this document to the first step so the tester can open it when running the test.

Comment: It looks like not very convenient as for me. Usually manual testing tools have some precondition field for initial settings.

Comment: Hmmmm... I'm afraid I do not have better ideas how to meet you needs.

Comment: I suggest using shared steps for the preconditions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to show the Summary data for the test case in Test Runner (I'm using MTM/VS2012). In the test runner, above the steps on the right side below the Configuration label is a downward chevron. Click that and it expands to show the test case summary.

Comment: I can't see any 'Configuration' label during test run
http://screencast.com/t/4zGBVhIpCu
Please suggest where it should be?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you have stored the preconditions in the test case. To see the preconditions information during test execution you need to add the information to the  description field in the summary tab

Comment: I have added the summary http://screencast.com/t/Ebho2modpX
But when I run the test I should press 'Edit' button to open test in edit mode to see this summary http://screencast.com/t/aOd5ySEI